# Remove/Replace the part of string value

Tags: java

I have to remove the words from the given string.

Example :

**Input:**

```
"H|013450107776|10/15/2019
D|0000TXN001|10/15/2019|013450107806|LCUATADA05|1000.00|PAYMENT FOR SERVICE|Successful"
```

**Output:**

```
"H|013450107776|10/15/2019
D|0000TXN001|10/15/2019|013450107806|LCUATADA05|1000.00|Successful"
```

Note:`"PAYMENT FOR SERVICE"` is a dynamic string value it can be any thing.

I have tried using replace() and regex function but i am not able to get the exact output.

Comment: can you show us your code?

Comment: you can split your input string using pipe "|" and then concat your split output without appending the ones you want to remove.

Comment: Regex is with `replaceAll`. Like `s = s.replaceAll("^(D\\|.*\\|)[^|]*\\[^|]*(\\|.*)$", "$1$2");`.

Comment: Is your search for removal driven by the _text_ content of the element (i.e. you know the text you want to remove), or is it driven by the _position_ of some text in the string?

Comment: Hi Vadiraj, did my answer solve your problem? [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: issue resolved thank you all

Answer (score 3):

The following code will work.

```
public static String replace(String original, String toRemove) {
    Arrays.stream(original.split("\\|"))
          .filter(s -> !(s.equals(toRemove)))
          .collect(Collectors.joining("|"));
}
```

First, create a `Stream` of `Strings` (`Stream<String>`) that are originally separated by `|`.

Second, filter them, so only `Strings` that are not equal to `toRemove` remain in the `Stream`.

Thrid, collect using `joining` with a joining character `|`.

Comment: ‍♂️ streams are in every place.

Comment: Yes they are :D The best thing of Java imo

Comment: use `str.split("\\|")` not `str.split("|")`

Comment: This is an elegant solution. Concise and easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

Splitting your string on "|" and assuming the word you want to replace is always at the same position, the below does what you need :

```
String s = "H|013450107776|10/15/2019D|0000TXN001|10/15/2019|013450107806|LCUATADA05|1000.00|PAYMENT FOR SERVICE|Successful";
String result = s.replace(s.split("\\|")[8], "");
System.out.println(result);
```

It prints out :

> H|013450107776|10/15/2019D|0000TXN001|10/15/2019|013450107806|LCUATADA05|1000.00||Successful

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick I like to use:

```
String input = "H|013450107776|10/15/2019D|0000TXN001|10/15/2019|013450107806|LCUATADA05|1000.00|PAYMENT FOR SERVICE|Successful";
System.out.println(input);
input = "|" + input + "|";
String output = input.replaceFirst("\\|PAYMENT FOR SERVICE\\|", "|");
output = output.substring(1, output.length()-1);
System.out.println(output);
```

To see how this works, consider the following input:

```
A|B|C
```

Let's say that we want to remove `A`.  We first form the string:

```
|A|B|C|
```

Then, we replace `|A|` with just `|`, to give:

```
|B|C|
```

Finally, we strip those initial added pipe separators to give:

```
B|C
```

Comment: This will probably outperform the answer which uses streams, which requires going from a string into a stream, and then back into a string.

Comment: I think your solution is wrong as it hardcodes `"PAYMENT FOR SERVICE"`. The OP mentioned this string could be different

Comment: I guess you're interpreting the question differently from me.  I assumed that the OP knows the _text_, but not the position.  You assumed the opposite, namely that the text doesn't matter, but the position does.

Comment: could be, however the input looks like CSV format so I think it's more likely that the position is known, but not the text

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "H|013450107776|10/15/2019D|0000TXN001|10/15/2019|013450107806|LCUATADA05|1000.00|PAYMENT FOR SERVICE|Successful";
        String scut = "PAYMENT FOR SERVICE";
        System.out.println(str.substring(0,str.indexOf(scut)) + str.substring(str.indexOf(scut)+scut.length()+1,str.length()));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
String str = "H|013450107776|10/15/2019D|0000TXN001|10/15/2019|013450107806|LCUATADA05|1000.00|PAYMENT FOR SERVICE|Successful";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("PAYMENT FOR SERVICE|", ""));`
```

Answer (score -3):

replace all uppercase words between || with "|"

for example: "|A G G SLG SD GSD G|" -> "|"

input.replaceAll("\\|[A-Z\\s]+\\|","|")

\\s - any whitespace symbol
A-Z - symbols between A and Z

more info : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html